# Capture AngularJS DATA_URI-based CSV

Tags: angularjs, csv, curl

I have an account with a reporting site that uses AngularJS and the CSV plugin to export our stats for a particular app. Working with the browser, I can click on 'Download CSV' and AngularJS uses the Data_URIs for downloading the CSV -- so, there is no server request.

Now, what I need is to be able to download this CSV using CURL. Since there is no server request, I can't reproduce that. Also scraping isn't a good idea since I don't want my backend to break when the HTML changes (obviously).

So, in summary: **How do I capture the CSV generated by the `getCSV()` function in AngularJS?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using a headless WebKit engine like phantomjs.

After a quick look and the angular js you can use this code to return the CSV content after you log in.

```
page.open('https://www.mobilecore.com/newdashboard/', function(status) {

    data = page.evaluate(function() {
        angular.element($('#getCsv')).scope().setCsvContent();
        return angular.element($('#getCsv')).scope().csvContent;
    });
    console.log(data);
});
```

To log in use this easy example: https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/post.js

Comment: Awesome! +1 for the conciseness.